# Where is bitcoind package?

Tags: release-management, bitcoin

I can't find `bitcoind` packages.

```
# apt-cache search bitcoin
bfgminer - multi-threaded multi-pool ASIC, FPGA and GPU bitcoin miner
cgminer - multi-threaded multi-pool Bitcoin miner
electrum - Easy to use bitcoin client
libblkmaker-0.1-0 - implementation of getblocktemplate protocol
libblkmaker-0.1-dev - C implementation of getblocktemplate protocol - development files
python-electrum - Easy to use bitcoin client - python module
```

What is the reason to remove bitcoind, but insert miners: cgminer, bfgminer?

Comment: Why was the question closed? It's a very clear question, at least to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit of Googling leads to [this bug](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bitcoin) for `bitcoin` in Ubuntu, which has this Ubuntu [MoTU mailing list post](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-motu/2013-December/007597.html). This passage, at the end, explains it:

> For these reasons and others, including the Bitcoin software in any stable,
>   no-updates release is not a good thing for Ubuntu users nor for the bitcoin
>   network as a whole. There is already a PPA, maintained by Matt Corallo, one
>   of the core developers, and linked to from http://bitcoin.org/en/download.
>   Said PPA provides both the Bitcoin software and the BDB 4.8 packages needed
>   for wallet compatibility with the software on other platforms. Over at
>   Debian, their Bitcoin Packaging Team has been maintaining the package,
>   keeping it in the unstable branch (sid) only, where it is allowed to be
>   updated with new releases of the software. It is not included in the stable
>   repository (wheezy), nor in testing (jessie). If I understand correctly,
>   Ubuntu doesn't have that kind of release. It is my opinion that, given
>   Ubuntu's methods of managing its software, it would be better to not
>   include Bitcoin in the Ubuntu repositories, unless exceptions to the
>   policies could be made, allowing all supported Ubuntu versions to get the
>   latest updates as they come down from upstream. As a first step, the
>   Bitcoin software should be removed from Trusty's repositories, assuming no
>   exception can be made. Ideally, it would also be removed from the older
>   repositories (Precise, Quantal, Raring, Saucy) if it can't be updated,
>   though I'm told that's significantly harder from the perspective of the
>   standard workflows.

The PPA mentioned is https://launchpad.net/~bitcoin/+archive/ubuntu/bitcoin.

As for `cgminer` and `bfgminer`, from what I understand, `bitcoind` is the daemon behind the Bitcoin wallet (and the CLI interface), and not a miner by itself. And `cgminer` is one of the more popular mining software out there.